# how to pass checked check boxes in a while loop to next page

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to pass the checked boxes from a group of check box in a while loop. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
$Q="
  select
    id,
    name 
  from
    dwincperiod 
  where
    `bid`='$bid' 
    and (
      (
        month(`fromdate`)='$month' 
        and year(`fromdate`)='$year'
      ) 
      or (
        month(`fromdate`)='$mon' 
        and year(`fromdate`)='$year'
      ) 
      or (
        month(`fromdate`)='$mnt' 
        and year(`fromdate`)='$year'
      )
    )";

$R = mysql_query($Q);
while ($ROW = mysql_fetch_array($R)) {
  $i++;
  $id   = $ROW[id];
  $name = $ROW[name];
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="incperiod' . $i . '" value="' . $id . '">' . $name . "<br/>";
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">';
}
```

Comment: don't practice lame variable declaration like `$Q, $R` make it more mearningful , `$Q = $query , $R = $result`

Comment: sorry @DrixsonOseña.. I just simply copied from over all program ... and i already named variables as $query and $result in some other places ..... Sorry sir

Comment: Actually what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a page contains many option for user to select. Once the user selected some options, the page will POST it to next page, and capture the user options. Now you are looking for a solution about this ??

Comment: @AllenChak ya you are right.....

Comment: in the next page my code is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the page let user to select:

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='incpreiod[]' value='{$id}' />{$name}</label><br />";
```

For getting user options

```
print_r($_POST['incpreiod']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM dwincperiod WHERE id IN ({$_POST['incpreiod']}) and bid='{$bid}'";
$resultset = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultset)) {
    ...
}
```

Remarks

Using `[]` to pass the data in array format
PS: To prevent SQL injection, I strongly recommend you don't pass data into query string.

Comment: in the next page my code is....
$check=$_post['check'];
for($a=0;$a<=$check;$a++)
{
  $in=$_POST['incperiod'.$a];
$Qdw="select * from dwincperiod where `id`='$in' and `bid`='$bid'";
$Rdw=mysql_query($Qdw);
while($Rowdw=mysql_fetch_array($Rdw))
{
 $fromdate=$Rowdw['fromdate'];
 $todate=$Rowdw['todate'];
 $did=$Rowdw['did']; 
}}

Comment: //$check ..which it means passing the value of $i,If in the first page i shows 30 check boxes and a user select only 3 among them ,,, in the next page when using the for loop ,,, it runs for all the 30 times and checks the value ... it tooks too long time .... how can i recover that .... sorry to every one for my poor communication ....